# Why does my code think 100 is smaller than 50?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I coded a small project that you can enter two numbers in and it will tell you what's smaller and what's bigger, what's the difference between them and if they're equal, but the code thinks that 100 is smaller than 50.. I've also entered numbers like `50;70` and `60;70`, but then it says the correct thing which is that the first number is smaller than the second one. I don't understand what's wrong, and how can I fix it? Here's my code, you can run it yourself so you can see what will happen.

```
import math
import time

num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))

difference = num1 - num2

if str(num1) > str(num2):
    print("--" + str(num1) + " is greater than " + str(num2) + ".")
    print("--The difference between " + str(num1) + " and " + str(num2) + " is " + str(difference) + "." )

elif str(num1) < str(num2):
    pass
    print("--" + str(num1) + " is smaller than " + str(num2))
    print("--The difference cannot be calculated because " + str(num1) + " is smaller than " + str(num2) + ".")

else:
    print(str(num1) + " and " + str(num2) + " are equal.")
```

Comment: Not sure why you are casting the nums to a string for the comparison or why you have a `pass` in the elif statement. You could also look at `f-strings` instead of `"" + "" + "" ...`

Comment: @JoshuaNixon is right; that is the problem. You compare them as strings not integers.

Comment: The string `"100"` _is_ smaller than the string `"50"`. Look up lexical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, as several commenters have pointed out, is that you're doing a string conversion on the input numbers.

As integers, 50 < 100, but for strings, ordering is done alphabetically - and "1" comes before "5", so "100" < "50".

Drop the `str()` calls and you should be good.